# Laravel 5.1 form::radio, cant get "false" from variable but when I type false it works

Tags: php, forms, laravel, radio-button, laravel-blade

this is my code

```
<div class="form-group">
{!! Form::label('', '*Role') !!}
@foreach ($roles as $role)
    <div class="radio">
        {!! Form::radio( 'role', $role->id, $user->getRolesCheckedAtrribute($user, $role), ['id' => $role->slug]) !!}
        {!! Form::label($role->slug, $role->name) !!}
        {!! $user->getRolesCheckedAtrribute($user, $role) !!}
    </div>
@endforeach
```

And the output is:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="">*Role</label>
        <div class="radio">
                    <input id="super-admin" checked="checked" name="role" value="1" type="radio">
        <label for="super-admin">Super Admin</label>
        false
    </div>
        <div class="radio">
                    <input id="admin" checked="checked" name="role" value="2" type="radio">
        <label for="admin">Admin</label>
        true
    </div>
        <div class="radio">
                    <input id="basic-user" checked="checked" name="role" value="3" type="radio">
        <label for="basic-user">Basic User</label>
        false
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that I cant get the value of `$user->getRolesCheckedAtrribute() inside of Form::radio`, but outside of it it echoes as it should. So every radio gets `checked="checked"` although only the second one has true.

If I replace "$user->getRolesCheckedAtrribute($user, $role)" in Form::radio() with "false", then none of the buttons get checked.

I'm using `Laravel 5.1` and require:

```
  "kodeine/laravel-acl": "~1.0@dev",
  "laravelcollective/html": "^5.1"
```

If you need more details please ask.

UPDATE:

```
 public function getRolesCheckedAtrribute($user, $role) {
    if (head($user->getRoles()) == $role->slug) {
        $checked = 'true';
    }
    else {
        $checked = 'false';
    }
    return $checked;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the function `getRolesCheckedAtrribute($user, $role)`?  I have a feeling it's implemented incorrectly in that it shouldn't echo anything, it should return either true or false.

Comment: I updated the question with the function. Function returns false or true. Check third row in div.radio:
{!! $user->getRolesCheckedAtrribute($user, $role) !!}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My assumptions were correct.

`return 'true'` is not the same as `return true`.  Additionally, `return 'false'` will actually evaluate to true which is why everything is checked.

Use `return true` or `return false` and it should solve your issue.

If you are unable to do that because this function is used elsewhere, you can also do...

```
`$user->getRolesCheckedAtrribute($user, $role) == 'true'`
```

So if your function returns 'true', it will return true, otherwise, it will evaluate correctly to false.

This may be what you would need to change your function to...

```
public function getRolesCheckedAtrribute($user, $role) {
    if (head($user->getRoles()) == $role->slug) {
        $checked = true;
    } else {
        $checked = false;
    }

    return $checked;
}
```

Comment: This solved the problem. I didn't realize that true/false in Form::radio function were actually boolean variables. Thank you.